# For an associative binary operation with identity, the set of invertible elements forms a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, binary-operations

Let $S$ be a set, and $*$ an associative binary operation on $S$. Suppose there is an element $e\in S$ such that

($1$) $e*x=x$ and $x*e=x$ for all $x\in S$.

(a) Prove that there is a unique element $e$ satisfying property $(1)$.

(b) Let $T=\{x\in S$ | there exist $y$, $z$ $\in S$ such that $y*x=e=x*z$}. Prove that $(T, *)$ is a group.

I understand ($1$) perfectly. However, I am completely lost on ($2$). I don't know how to proceed to verify the group axioms. Any help/solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not edit your question after it has been answered.

Comment: Maybe no one is doing this because this site is not intended for tutoring (or solving problems _on demand_)...

Comment: "Hurry!  Why isn't anyone doing this?"  **Seriously!?!?**  People who ask questions like this are going to drive me away from this site eventually.  There is no reason any question *deserves* to get an answer--if anyone responds at all, consider it like an incredible gift!  Don't be demanding.

Comment: @user133281 You should roll back the edits when this happens.

Comment: (Also, I am voting to re-open this question because the original question was fine. It is the self-defacing that is the issue.)

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to show that $e \in T$ (since $e \ast e = e$) and that $e$ acts as a unit element. Furthermore, $T$ contains inverses of its elements. By definition, the operation $\ast$ is associative. The most tricky part is showing that $T$ is closed under $\ast$. Suppose that $a$, $b \in T$. Then we have to show that $a \ast b$ is in $T$ as well, thus we have to show that there exists $c,d \in T$ such that $a \ast b \ast c = e$ and $d \ast a \ast b = e$. We know that there is an $x \in T$ such that $b \ast x = e$ and that there is a $y \in T$ such that $a \ast y = e$. Then we have $a \ast b \ast (x \ast y) = e$, so we can take $c = x \ast y$. Analogously, we can find a suitable choice for $d$. (Note that it is not required that $x \ast y$ is itself in $T$, only that it is in $S$.)

**Edit:**

Why is $e$ in $T$? Because there exist $y,z \in S$ such that $y \ast e = e = e \ast z$. One can take $y=z=e$ since $e \ast e = e$ (applying $e \times x = x$ with $x = e$).

Why contains $T$ inverses of its elements? Suppose $a \in T$. Then there are $b,c \in S$ with $a \ast b = e$ and $c \ast a = e$. This means that $c = c \ast e = c \ast (a \ast b) = c \ast a \ast b = (c \ast a) \ast b = e \ast b = b$, hence $b = c$. So we have $a \ast b = e$ and $b \ast a = e$. Note that this implies that $b \in T$, and therefore $b$ is an inverse of $a$.

Comment: What is T? Where is it defined?

Comment: This question was edited. The original question mentioned a set $S$ equipped with a binary associative operation $\ast$, an element $e \in S$ with $x \ast e = e \ast x = x$ for all $x \in S$, and asked to show that the set $T = \{x \in S: y \ast x = e, x \ast z = e \mbox{ for some } y,z \in S\}$ is a group under $\ast$.